# rename year field in $project in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to rename my ID field in the project phase but I have an error message. The $match and $sort phases work fine. Here are the details:

```
db.complaints.aggregate([
    {$match:{$text:{$search:"\"loan\""}}},
    {$group:{"_id":{Year:{$substr: ["$received", 0, 4]}}, "loan":{$sum:1}}},
    {$sort:{_id:-1}},
    {$project:{_id:0, "Year":"_id.Year", "loan":1}}
])
```

Here is my schema:

```
> db.complaints.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e5990d991312e2c9b266e3"),
    "complaintID" : 1388734,
    "product" : "mortgage",
    "subProduct" : "conventional adjustable mortgage (arm)",
    "issue" : "loan servicing, payments, escrow account",
    "subIssue" : "",
    "state" : "va",
    "ZIP" : 22204,
    "submitted" : "web",
    "received" : "2015-05-22",
    "sent" : "2015-05-22",
    "company" : "green tree servicing, llc",
    "response" : "closed with explanation",
    "timely" : "yes",
    "disputed" : ""
}
```

Comment: Needs to be prefixed with a `$` i.e `"$_id.Year"`. Don't do it though as it costs to do such projection. Just reference the `_id` property or transpose in code.

Comment: Thanks Blake for your reply. But I would like to display result on front end. What would be the best approach from performance point of view.

Comment: The best approach would be to train your front end to accept the field as `_id` therefore removing any overhead from either the aggregation pipeline processing or the client. It is afterall the "unique key" for each returned document, and should be treated as such.

Comment: Thank you very much. I highly appreciate your advice. kindest Regards